# C# - NUnit - 'dependsOnMethods' from TestNG

Tags: c#, nunit

With TestNG we have the "dependsOnMethods" feature that cheks if another TC has passed to execute the current TC and if it has a fail it does not execute unless you add alwaysRun label, as shown below:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods={ "testMethod2" }, alwaysRun=true)
public void testMethod1() {
    System.out.println("testMethod1");
}

@Test
public void testMethod2() {
    System.out.println("testMethod2");
    int result = 3;
    Assert.assertEquals(result, 2);
}
```

Is there any way to have the same behaviour using NUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NUnit's own facilties, there is no way to do this. There has been a lot of discussion around adding this sort of dependency, but it does not yet exist. Maybe TestNG is a good model for a future Attribute.

Currently, all you can do is order tests in NUnit. So, if you gave `testMethod2` the attribute [Order(1)] it would run before any other tests in the fixture. This has some limitations:

1. Ordering has to do with starting tests, not waiting for them to finish. In a parallel environment, both tests could still run together. So, to use this workaround, you should not run the tests in the fixture in parallel. Fixtures can still run in parallel against one another, of course.
2. There is no provision that `testMethod2` must **pass** in order for `testMethod1` to be run. You could handle this yourself by setting an instance field in `testMethod2` and testing it in `testMethod1`. I would probably test it using `Assume.That` so that test method 1 is not displayed as a warning or error in the case that test method 2 failed.